# AWS Role chaning for GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam

I am pretty new to AWS and struggling with role chaining for my github-actions-role.

I have a role “GithubActionsRole” which has the following Permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:SetSourceIdentity"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NO:role/cdk-contactupd-deploy-role-ACCOUNT_NO-REGION
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this Trust relationships:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::ACC_NO:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "sts:SetSourceIdentity"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:my-repo/sub-dir:*”
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So now, the  GithubActionsRole should assume the role “cdk-contactupd-deploy-role-ACCOUNT_NO-REGION”. This role is configured like this: 
Persmissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "CloudFormationPermissions"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust relationships:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NO:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:SetSourceIdentity"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my GitHub-action I execute the following:

```
… - name: Set nonlive variables
        run: |
          echo "STAGE=nonlive" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "GITHUB_ROLE=arn:aws:iam::ACC_NO:role/GithubActionsRole" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-region: MY_REGION
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.GITHUB_ROLE }}
- run: aws sts get-caller-identity
- name: Deploy CDK Stacks
…
```

Unfortunately the last step is failing with the following Message:

```
    failed: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/GithubActionsRole/GitHubActions is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:...:stack/MY_STACK/... because no identity-based policy allows the cloudformation:DescribeStacks action.
```

But the "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"-policy should be allowed through the role chaining from the ""cdk-contactupd-deploy-role-ACCOUNT_NO-REGION" role.

I appreciate any idea how to fix it. I tried already a lot the last few days :/